# Can jQuery select by CSS rule, not class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

A `.container` can contain many `.components`, and `.components` themselves can contain `.containers` (which in turn can contain .components etc. etc.)

Given code like this:

```
$(".container .component").each(function(){
  $(".container", this).css('border', '1px solid #f00');
});
```

What do I need to add to the line within the braces to select only the nested `.containers` that have their `width` in CSS set to `auto`?  I'm sure it's something simple, but I haven't really used jQuery all that much.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies.

I would have ideally liked to include the CSS rule within the selector, so that I had a group of all the .containers that are within a .component that have a CSS width: auto, but never mind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$(".container .component").each(function()
{
    $(".container", this).each(function() {
        if($(this).css('width') == 'auto')
        {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid #f00');
        }
    });
});
```

Similar to the other answer but since components can also have multiple containers, also needs the .each() check in here too for the width.

Answer (score 20):

You may want to look into `.filter()`.

Something like:

```
$('.container .component .container')
.filter(function() {return $(this).css('width') == 'auto';})
.css({border: '1px solid #f00'});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".container .component").each(function() {
    if ($(".container", this).css('width') === "auto")
        $(".container", this).css('border', '1px solid #f00');
});
```