# find in jquery applying css to all span

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors

i am making a tree with the help of js and jquery in asp.net mvc.

there is a add button which add the sibling and same level child .

to identify what is to be done i am using the following code.

```
    //to check from where the function is called
     var checkClass = $('#UlPrnt').find('span').css('background-color', 'Lime').length;
        if (checkClass == 0) {
            AddSiblings();
        $('#hdnChkSibbling').val('2');
        }
        else {
            debugger         
            var getValue = $('#dvTree').find('span').css('background-color', 'Lime');
            var spnID = getValue[1].id;
            var check = spnID.indexOf("spn");
            if (check>0) {
                AddSiblings();
                $('#'+spnID).css('background-color', '');
            }
            else {
                //call the function to append the same level child
            }

        }
```

when i was going through the find function in jquery what i interpreted is that it will return the no of dom where the corresponding bg color is lime.

but what it does it applys the bgcolor to all the span .

how to get the ids of the span whose bgcolor is lime.

every thing is created dynamically (span ,div) just wanted to add for getting a better picture.

Answer (score 6):

You're using the jQuery .css() method incorrectly. You use .css() to **get** or to **set** a css property. For more details see: http://api.jquery.com/css/.

Instead of using css, you should add a class to all elements that you want to be lime-colored:

```
$('???').addClass('lime-colored');
```

Then, in your css file, specify the styling for the lime-colored class:

```
.lime-colored { background-color:lime; }
```

Then, when you want to grab all of the elements that are currently green, do so by grabbing the elements that have the lime-colored class appended:

```
var checkClass = $('#UlPrnt').find('span.lime-colored').length;
```

If you want to remove lime coloring, you can use the following:

```
$('???').removeClass('lime-colored');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through each then find the attribute lime. Here is an example:
[jQuery: Can you select by CSS rule, not class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926/jquery-can-you-select-by-css-rule-not-class)

Another approach though would be to add a class (like background-lime) when you change the background to lime. Then just search for that class, $.(".background-lime").

Comment: hi mattimus that can be done that u suggested but it was increasing

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $('#UlPrnt span')
 //a set of spans with background-color of lime
 .filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('background-color')=='lime';
 })
 //a set of ids
 .map(function(){ return this.id; });
```