# Find element with specified z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find HTML element(-s) with `z-index` = 10 for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can you select by CSS rule, not class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926/jquery-can-you-select-by-css-rule-not-class)

Comment: also: [jQuery find by inline css attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180067/jquery-find-by-inline-css-attribute)

Comment: Don't. If you're using this approach, you're probably doing something wrong. Use ids or classes instead.

Comment: also: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291605/jquery-select-style-attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291605/jquery-select-style-attribute)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to iterate over all elements and check their z-index:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('z-index') == 10;
}).each(function() {
    // do something with them   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Without JQuery:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
  .filter(e=>getComputedStyle(e).zIndex >= 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible [jQuery] solution:

```
$(".elementsToSearch").each(function()
{
    if($(this).css('z-index') == 10)
    {
        //then it's a match
    }
});
```

Just loops through elements searching for a match to the css rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all elements and filter them by css property:

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('z-index') == 10) {
        //$(this) - is element what you need
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my testing in Chrome 43, I found [@ThiefMaster's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143923/444382) to be helpful, but not 100%. The value of the `z-index` being pulled was a string.

I also made this only iterate over visible elements and handle `auto`.

Here's my update:

```
var topZ = $('.thing-in-front').css('z-index')
if (topZ != 'auto') {
    topZ = parseInt(topZ);
    $('*:visible').filter(function() {
        var thisZ = $(this).css('z-index')
        return thisZ != 'auto' && parseInt(thisZ) >= topZ;
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', topZ - 1);
    })
}
```