# jQuery: Select elements where align = "center"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select only paragraphs where align="center" (inline styling).

```
jQuery(p.MsoNormal).attr('align', 'center').addClass('av-tablecell');
```

This seems to select all paragraph elements, even without align=center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926/jquery-can-you-select-by-css-rule-not-class

Comment: @SomeKittens except that `align` is just an attribute, not a CSS property.

Comment: Whoops, a bit hasty on my part.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is setting the "align" attribute on p.MsoNormal to "center".  You need to include it in your selection to get only the elements that already have "align=center" like so:

```
jQuery('p.MsoNormal[align="center"]').addClass('av-tablecell');
```

Answer (score 6):

Try like below,

```
jQuery('p.MsoNormal[align=center]').addClass('av-tablecell');
```